# How can I obtain the percentage increase in a graphite value over several consecutive time periods?

Tags: graphite

I have several queue lengths stored as gauges in Graphite and I need to form a query URL which checks for a certain trend. Specifically, I need to know if a queue is:

> ...growing at a rate of more than 15% over three consecutive 1 hour periods.

I have tried various approaches including:

```
summarize(derivative(queue.length),"3h",avg)
```

...and various options with a `timeStack(queue.length,"1h",3)` series, but I just can't work it out.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The nearest I have got so far is to use the `minSeries` function and pass in three `asPercent` pairs, each with a `timeShift` function applied.

Comment: For instance:  
`minSeries(asPercent(queue.length,timeShift(queue.length,"1h"),asPercent(queue.length,timeShift(queue.length,"2h")),asPercent(queue.length,timeShift(queue.length,"3h")))`  
  
My reasoning is that if any of those values are above 115, then the particular condition above must be true.  
The results are a bit odd though. I'm not sure it's working yet.

Comment: how about `current / 3 hours ago - 1`? it doesn't measure the consecutive increase part, but it shows the percentage increase compares to 3 hours ago.

Comment: Thanks @fabricator.
Unfortunately, that's not quite sufficient because our queues quite often increase quickly and then decrease slowly, which means after 3 hours we might still have more than the original value.